# MSAL authentication with WKWebView or SFSafariViewController on iOS 13/14 (Connect Native and WebView to SSO authentication)

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, azure-ad-msal, sfsafariviewcontroller

Scenario:
Application open and user sign in with MSAL thru ASWebAuthenticationSession, or custom WKWebView.

```
webViewParamaters?.webviewType = .authenticationSession
```

after that, I have the access token and can GET data.
When I open WKWebView or SFSafariViewController with a secure website that is using the same MSAL authentication service, it is asking for authentication again.

Can I send access token/cookies or do something so will not ask for authentication the second time when I open WKWebView or SFSafariViewController?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to find a solution? @zdravko

Comment: No, even after talking to Microsoft support, I start using SFSafariViewController, and users must sign-in once before opening the web page. Cookies are not transferred in webview.